# How to generate an exhaustive list of sequences with N elements choosing from C objects?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function that outputs a dictionary like this:

```
0: [0,0,0]
1: [0,0,1]
2: [0,0,2]
...
n: [0,0,n]
n+1: [0,1,0]
n+2: [0,1,1]
...
n^3: [n,n,n]
```

This example is when the list is 3 elements long. I'd like to generalize this to lists of arbitrary length.

Here's some code I have tried already which works for 3 element long lists. Clearly can extend this to arbitrary lengths by adding more for loops, but I'm sure there is a better way.

```
tricount = 0
wgtlist = [0.0, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0, 60.0, 70.0, 80.0, 90.0, 100.0]
for i in range(0, len(wgtlist)):
    for j in range (0, len(wgtlist)):
        for k in range (0, len(wgtlist)):
            trilist = []
            trilist.append(wgtlist[i])
            trilist.append(wgtlist[j])
            trilist.append(wgtlist[k])
            trials[tricount] = trilist
            tricount = tricount+1
print (trials)
```

This outputs:

```
{0: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 1: [0.0, 0.0, 10.0], 2: [0.0, 0.0, 20.0], 3: [0.0, 0.0, 30.0], 4: [0.0, 0.0, 40.0], 5: [0.0, 0.0, 50.0], 6: [0.0, 0.0, 60.0], 7: [0.0, 0.0, 70.0], 8: [0.0, 0.0, 80.0], 9: [0.0, 0.0, 90.0], 10: [0.0, 0.0, 100.0], 11: [0.0, 10.0, 0.0], 12: [0.0, 10.0, 10.0], 13: [0.0, 10.0, 20.0].....

1323: [100.0, 100.0, 30.0], 1324: [100.0, 100.0, 40.0], 1325: [100.0, 100.0, 50.0], 1326: [100.0, 100.0, 60.0], 1327: [100.0, 100.0, 70.0], 1328: [100.0, 100.0, 80.0], 1329: [100.0, 100.0, 90.0], 1330: [100.0, 100.0, 100.0]}
```

(obviously truncated output)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.product` on the list with a `repeat` of the number of items you would like in the output tuples. Since the keys of your expected output dict are simply incremental numbers starting from `0`, it would be more efficient use a list instead of a dict:

```
from itertools import product
trials = list(product(wgtlist, repeat=3))
```

or with an equivalent recursive generator:

```
def product(seq, repeat):
    if repeat:
        for i in seq:
            for p in product(seq, repeat - 1):
                yield [i, *p]
    else:
        yield []
```

Comment: thank you! Is there a way to do this just using for loops and recursive function? or am I asking a stupid question?

Comment: With `for` loops you won't be able to nest an arbitrary number of `for` loops. I've updated my answer with a recursive solution for your reference.